# Can't open the wallet (Windows 10, 64 bit)

Tags: wallets, mist, windows, bug

Only thing I have is an image saying

> Starting Ethereum node...

If I quit and start it again it says:

> Couldn't start an Ethereum node! Are you already running a node

Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Which version of Mist are your running? 0.4.0 or earlier?

Comment: 0.4.0  Do I need command line tools?

Comment: What makes you think you need command line tools? You could of course opt to [manage accounts through geth for now](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth).

Answer (score 2):

The current Mist wallet [has a number of open issues on Windows](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues). Fixes are in progress but not available as of yet.

Issues that resemble yours:

- [Mist not starting up](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/197)
- [Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-4-0 does not start in windows 10](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/202)

You can help the developers by either creating a new issue (if your problem is unique, which it might be because my quick scan didn't see issues explicitly involving `Starting Ethereum node...`) or reporting your case on an existing issue.

You should also provide them with the logs: go to `%APPDATA%/Roaming/Mist/` and copy all the `*.log` files, as suggested by frozeman in the second link. You could also check them out yourself and see if you find anything meaningful.